# Remove Duplicate based on column value-linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

i have many to many relationship between employee and group.  following linq statement

```
int[] GroupIDs = {6,7};


var result = from g in umGroups
    join empGroup in umEmployeeGroups on g.GroupID equals empGroup.GroupID
    where  GroupIDs.Contains(g.GroupID)                     
    select new {  GrpId = g.GroupID,EmployeeID = empGroup.EmployeeID };
```

returns groupid and the employeeid. and result is

```
GrpId  | EmployeeID
6      |   18
6      |   20  
7      |   19
7      |   20
```

I need to remove the rows for which the employeeid is repeating e.g. any one of the row with employeeid= 20

Thanks

Comment: What would make it remove the last row rather than the one with GrpId=6?

Comment: ok, i need result with distinct Employeeids any one can be removed

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Okay, if you don't care which employee is removed, you could try something like:

```
var result = query.GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
                  .Select(group => group.First());
```

You haven't specified whether this is in LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Objects or something else... I don't know what the SQL translation of this would be. If you're dealing with a relatively small amount of data you could always force this last bit to be in-process:

```
var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
                  .Select(group => group.First());
```

At that point you could actually use [MoreLINQ](https://morelinq.github.io/) which has a handy [`DistinctBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.10/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_DistinctBy__2.htm) method:

```
var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .DistinctBy(x => x.EmployeeId);
```

Comment: just for curiosity! what if i want to remove specific row based on groupid.

Comment: @Tassadaque: You'd have to give more details about what you want - but you could potentially use `Except` or `Where`.

Comment: That's a great extension!

Comment: It's worked, thank you.